# React.js how to return commented video tag for ie9 support

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-9, components, render

Let's say in React I want to support ie9 by wrapping my code, as this example for [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) does:

```
<picture>
  <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
  <source srcset="examples/images/extralarge.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
  <source srcset="examples/images/large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <img srcset="examples/images/medium.jpg" alt="…">
</picture>
```

In react, that would be:

```
return (
                <picture>
                <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
                <source type="image/webp" className="full-photo2 slide-init" srcSet={"./build/assets/images/photos/responsive/webp/" + image.id + "-400.webp 400w, ./build/assets/images/photos/responsive/webp/" + image.id + "-800.webp 800w, ./build/assets/images/photos/responsive/webp/" + image.id + "-1000.webp 1000w,"} />
                <img className="full-photo2 slide-init" srcSet={"./build/assets/images/photos/responsive/jpg/" + image.id + "-400.jpg 400w, ./build/assets/images/photos/responsive/jpg/" + image.id + "-800.jpg 800w, ./build/assets/images/photos/responsive/jpg/" + image.id + "-1000.jpg 1000w,"} />
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->  
            </picture>
 )
```

Of course, React gets angry about this.

So how can you return IE9 hacks like this in your React returns?

Comment: While it's discouraged to use, you could try https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: How would this work with the comment syntax?

Comment: I'm thinking something like this (not tested) https://gist.github.com/djkirby/a6ef3e60ffc213b095da

Comment: see https://nemisj.com/conditional-ie-comments-in-react-js/

Comment: File a bug on React to support inserting HTML comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the caveats about using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as per the above link, this is what I have made work (using ES6):-

```
const createMarkup = () => {
  return  {__html:
    `<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcSet="examples/images/extralarge.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <source srcSet="examples/images/large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img src="examples/images/medium.jpg" alt="…">`
  };
};

return (
  <picture dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()}>
  </picture>
)
```

You can of course also pass arguments into the `createMarkup` function and interpolate those within the template string as placeholders using the `${ }` syntax ([Getting Literal With ES6 Template Strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en)):-

```
const createMarkup = (path) => {
  return  {__html:
    `<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcSet="${path}extralarge.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <source srcSet="${path}large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img src="${path}medium.jpg" alt="…">`
  };
};

return (
  <picture dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup('examples/images/')}>
  </picture>
)
```